# undefined reference to `Teste_1::Teste_1

Tags: c++, include

Geralmente dizem que não se inclui o .cpp no main e sim o .h, porém no meu caso sempre que vou incluir o .h dá erro e não sei porque.

segue o código:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Teste_1.h"

int main(){

    Teste_1 *test=new Teste_1("you never win! but you can get my money", "Hello");

    delete test;
    return 0;
}
```

Teste_1.h

```
#ifndef TESTE_1_H_INCLUDED
#define TESTE_1_H_INCLUDED

class Teste_1{
    private:
        std::string var_str1;
        std::string var_str2;
    public:
        Teste_1(std::string var1, std::string var2);
        ~Teste_1();
};

#endif // TESTE_1_H_INCLUDED
```

Teste_1.cpp

```
#include "Teste_1.h"

Teste_1::Teste_1(std::string var1, std::string var2){
    var_str1=var1;
    var_str2=var2;
}

Teste_1::~Teste_1(){

}
```

Sim! Sim! o código não possui o menor sentido, mais idai? É só um exemplo de erro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dica #1:**

Sempre que um `.h` ou um `.cpp` possuir referências externas, o header dessa referência externa deve ser incluído. Isso aumenta o desacoplamento entre os módulos e melhora a legibilidade do código.

Referências:

1. *SoftwareEngineering*: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262019/is-it-good-practice-to-rely-on-headers-being-included-transitively

**Dica #2:**

Usar sempre a palavra reservada `void` em métodos/funções que não recebem parametros, por exemplo, substituir `T::foobar()` por `T::foobar(void)` é uma excelente prática pois:

1. Melhora a legibilidade: `T::foobar()` se parece com uma chamada
   enquanto `T::foobar(void)` se parece com uma implementação e/ou
   definição);
2. Melhora a interpretação do código pelo compilador, evitando um
   problema chamado *[most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)*;
3. Garante compatibilidade com interfaces em `C`, pois em `C` a
   funções declaradas como `foobar()` não possuem o mesmo significado
   que funções declaradas como `foobar(void)`.

Referências:

1. *Wikipedia:* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse
2. *StackOverflow:* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c

**Dica #3:**

Sempre usar destrutores virtuais nas definições de classe é uma outra boa prática, isso permite manipulações polimorficas, permite `cascatear` a chamada do destrutores da classe derivada para as classes base, evitando *leaks* de memória.

Referências:

1. *StackOverflow:* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors

**Dica #4:**

Os construtores de classe permitem que você inicialize os seus membros em uma lista de inicialização, isso foi feito para ser usado! Evite inicializar seus membros de classe dentro da implementação do construtor.

Referências:

1. *StackOverflow:* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683010/best-practice-for-class-member-initialization
2. *StackOverflow:* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927169/how-can-i-initialize-c-object-member-variables-in-the-constructor

Como ficaria o seu código:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Teste_1.h"

int main(void){
    Teste_1 * test = new Teste_1( "you never win! but you can get my money", "Hello" );
    delete test;
    return 0;
}
```

**Teste_1.h:**

```
#ifndef TESTE_1_H_INCLUDED
#define TESTE_1_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

class Teste_1{
    private:
        std::string var_str1;
        std::string var_str2;
    public:
        Teste_1( std::string var1, std::string var2 );
        virtual ~Teste_1(void);
};

#endif // TESTE_1_H_INCLUDED
```

**Teste_1.cpp**

```
#include "Teste_1.h"
#include <string>

Teste_1::Teste_1( std::string var1, std::string var2 ) :
    var_str1(var1),
    var_str2(var2)
{
}

Teste_1::~Teste_1(void){
}
```

Compilando:

```
$ g++ main.cpp Teste_1.cpp -o teste
```

Comment: Continua com o erro: main.cpp|4|undefined reference to `Teste_1::Teste_1(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'|

Answer (score 0):

Antes da definição da classe `Teste_1` no arquivo cabeçalho **Teste_1.h**, inclua a biblioteca `string`:

```
#ifndef TESTE_1_H_INCLUDED
#define TESTE_1_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

class Teste_1 {
    ...
```

Depois disso, compile os arquivos fontes:

```
# g++ main.cpp Teste_1.cpp
```

Esse comando irá gerar um arquivo executável **a.exe**.